# reset and remove existing firewall port redirect rules in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, iptables

I have the following firewall settings in iptables.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8181
```

Now I want to reset and remove these redirection from firewall, I commented out the above two lines , tried iptables -F, but the redirection still exists.

How to reset and remove the redirection from firewall permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use -D in those rules to permanently delete those entries from firewall settings

```
# delete redirection http
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
# delete redirection https
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8181
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below command and change port 80 and 443 as your redirected port

```
*iptables -D PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 443*
```